# Determine installed ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle versions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've looked around a bit on how to get the versions of the installed ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundles. I know that the "Bundle" consists of the ASP.NET Core Module(V2) for IIS, and the .NET Core Runtime itself.

The Problem is, that I have a ASP.NET Core 2.1 and a ASP.NET Core 3.1 app that need to run on the very same IIS, which is why I need to know if both "bundles" are installed. Most answers around here focus on the .NET Core runtime itself and end on `dotnet --info` or `dotnet --list-runtimes` which shows me all the installed runtimes, but iin case of `--info` only the highest installed "host".

Since some older answers center around the path that dotnet is installed in, I looked that one up, and to my surprise, within `%ProgramFiles%\dotnet` there is a `host` folder contianing subfolders with the versions of the bundles that were installed. Within each is a `hostfxr.dll`.

So my question is, can I determine by that folder structure which versions of the ASP.NET Core Hosting bundles were installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems, that folder path has nothing to do with the hosting package.

But what's more important, an IIS that was installed after .NET Core doesn't seem to recognize the AspNetCoreModule(V2) at all. This means, that I always need to install the hosting package, no matter if the IIS is present or not, just to be sure.

Comment: Yes, but only once. V2 is V2 and at least not changing with .NET core versions ;) If you self-host the runtime (i.e. do not rely on an installed runtime) you can mix and match as you want without problems.

Comment: If I could rewind time, I would self-host all of it, not even using IIS in the first place. But well, that's hindsight.

Comment: No, makes no sense. You WANT IIS in the game - because there is a TON IIS does that otherwise does not happen. But IIS can bascially use AspNetCoreModule(v2) to load a website and the website can BRING IT'S OWN RUNTIME, so this is part of deployment.

Comment: I know, but it also brings it's own complexities, which at this point I think are heavier then letting kestrel do all the work, but cannot change back. (yes I already ran full-self-hosted). Also this get's Off-Topic now.

Answer (score 5):

The path to the Asp.Net Core Module v2 module is:

```
%Program Files%\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2
```

The install order of hosting bundles doesn't matter, you can install 5.0 then 3.1 then 2.1 in that order and the module version will be the latest major version from the newest bundle (in this example from 5.0 it will be v15.x)

- Installing a newer major version of the hosting bundle will update the module
- Installing a older major version of the hosting bundle will not update or replace the module if an existing newer major version already installed

The module is backwards compatible as far as I can tell. The v15.x module installed by the 5.x hosting bundle works for 3.x, 2.x and 1.x

The version numbers are aligned, 3.x installs module v13.x, 5.x installs module v15 and 6.x installs module 16.x etc.

The command to list the runtimes installed is:

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
```

You can view commits affecting the v2 module here
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/commits/main/src/Servers/IIS/AspNetCoreModuleV2